# switch upsell and related product on product page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have for some reason inherited a fully operating eCommerce (magento) where upsell and related products has been switched around when products were added. So in the old theme (using now) they have been switched in the front-end code, not in the back-end setup.

The result is thus, that in my new theme all related and upsell are in the wrong position. See result of new theme here: https://skarpe-1172.rask1.raskesider.no/18cm-kokkekniv-neo-kengata-masahiro.html

The knives should be in related, and the honing rod (bottom) etc should be in the top.

How can I change them? catalog.xml? If so, how?

**Upsell**

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">   
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>   
<action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit>
</action> </block>
```

**Related**

```
<reference name="right"> <block type="catalog/product_list_related"
name="catalog.product.related" before="-"
template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/> </reference>
```

Comment: I really dont want to go through 400+ products changing them.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution for this? Having the same issue, cannot find a resolve anywhere. Have tried `<move element="catalog.product.upsell" destination="content" before="-"/>` and `<move element="catalog.product.upsell" destination="content" before="catalog.product.related"/>` but to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

have you try something like this replace code with the following

Related

```html
<block type="catalog/product_list_related"
name="catalog.product.related" before="-"
template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

Upsell

```html
<reference name="right"> 
 <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">   
  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>   
  <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action> 
 </block>
</reference>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Hi, sorry - this did not work. Any other suggestions?